# Given a string which holds the name of a class, how can I then call a generic method using that class as the type parameter in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, methods, types

I am using the CreateTable method in SQLite-Net, which takes a type argument to specify what kind of table is being created. For example:

```
database.CreateTable<Client>();
```

Where client is defined as:

```
[Table("Client")]
public class Client
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

}
```

Would create a table with the schema defined in the client class, so having ClientID, Name, and Type columns.

I would like to use a string array, holding the names of the tables I want to create, to run CreateTable on all of the classes named in the array. However I'm unsure on how to use a string as a type parameter in a generic method.

It would look something like this:

```
string[] tables = new string[]{"Class1","Class2"};
for(int i = 0; i < tables.Length; i++){
    database.CreateTable<tables[i]>();
}
```

Which would do the same thing as this:

```
database.CreateTable<Class1>():
database.CreateTable<Class2>();
```

I've already tried to do it like this:

```
Type tabletype = Type.GetType("Client");
database.CreateTable<tabletype>();
```

But I get an error which says "The type or namespace name 'tabletype' could not be found". All the tables are defined as classes in the same namespace.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Generic type arguments have to be actual type names. They can't be expressions that evaluate to `Type` objects.

SQLite-Net already has a [non-generic overload of `CreateTable`](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/0e8bc3e8503efa0346020a4953d35c37199d136e/src/SQLite.cs#L383) that you should use for this case:

```
Type tabletype = Type.GetType("Client");
database.CreateTable(tabletype);
```

or

```
string[] tables = new[] { "Class1", "Class2" };
for(int i = 0; i < tables.Length; i++) {
    Type tableType = Type.GetType(tables[i]);
    database.CreateTable(tableType);
}
```

In the more general case, you'd have to use reflection with `MakeGenericMethod` to invoke the method with a Type that comes from an expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Reflection.

[How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)

Using your code example:

```
var database = GetDatabase(); // not sure what this type is.

MethodInfo method = database.GetType().GetMethod("CreateTable");
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); // Assume Class1, Class2 etc are here.

var tables = new string[] { "Class1","Class2" };

for(int i = 0; i < tables.Length; i++)
{
    MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(assembly.GetType(tables[i]););
    generic.Invoke(database, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, your type name should include the namespace when calling `Type.GetType` and the full name of the type should be nonambiguous:

```
public Type GetTableType(string name) {
    const string NamespacePrefix = "MyApp.Tables.";
    return Type.GetType(NamespacePrefix + name);
}
```

When you have the type, you need to use reflection to call your generic method, since there is no way to determine the type at compile time:

```
string tableName = "BlaTable";
var genericMethodTemplate = database.GetType().GetMethod("CreateTable", new Type[0]);
//genericMethodTemplate can be seen as database.CreateTable<T>();
var tableType = GetTableType(tableName);
var genericMethod = genericMethodTemplate.MakeGenericMethod(tableType);
//now the T has been filled in with whatever table was given.
genericMethod.Invoke(database);
```